# Refresh span value and show in alert using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown with three options: `soft`, `medium` and `hard`. `onchange` I am showing price in a `span`. When user selects `soft` price is `1000` & `medium` is `1500`, and `hard` is `2000`.

The problem is that my `alert()` is executing before the `span` gets refreshed, but I want to show the `alert` after the price gets refreshed. How can i do this?

```
<span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>0</span>
```

```js
$('.support-layer-firmness').on('change', function (e) {
   // onchange I am getting old value, if i select soft i am getting 0 instead of 1000
   var price = $('span.amount').text();
   alert(price);
});
```

**Html**

```
<li class="tmcp-field-wrap">
       <label for="tmcp_select_1"></label>
            <select class="tmcp-field support-layer-firmness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_0">
                         <option value="Select Firmness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="">Select Firmness</option>
                         <option value="Soft_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1000">Soft</option>
                         <option value="Medium_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1500">Medium</option>
                         <option value="Hard_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="2000">Hard</option>    
             </select>
<span class="price tc-price  hidden">
     <span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1,000</span>
 </span>
```

Comment: When do you update the value ?

Comment: The only way the `alert()` would be shown before the content is updated is if you are using an AJAX request. If so, you should use a callback function on that request to set the new price

Comment: What's updating the `span`?  Where does that value come from?  You can show your `alert` *after* that happens, or get your `alert` value from wherever the `span` gets its value.  If you're having a problem with two events happening out of sequence, you're going to want to look at *both* events and not just one of them.

Comment: @Rayon onchange I am updating but problem is it's showing old value instead of updated one

Comment: @websmentor.com Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @websmentor.com Nothing in your posted code updates `span` value... Anyway, your posted code, without relevant context nor any HTML markup is completly useless... Provide MCVE

Comment: @Rayon I have created fiddle but it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/19mpefjs/

Comment: @websmentor.com Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/19mpefjs/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `jQuery.text` method with no argument will return `textContent` of the element and if argument is set, `textContent` of the element will be set!

In your example, you never set the `textContent` of the element, Use `jQuery.data` to get the `data-price` value and then use `jQuery.text(VALUE)` to set the `textContent` of the element.

```js
$('.support-layer-firmness').on('change', function(e) {
  var price = $(this).find('option:selected').data('price')
  $('span.amount').text(price);
  alert(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="tmcp-field-wrap">
  <label for="tmcp_select_1"></label>
  <select class="tmcp-field support-layer-firmness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_0">
    <option value="Select Firmness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="">Select Firmness</option>
    <option value="Soft_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1000">Soft</option>
    <option value="Medium_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1500">Medium</option>
    <option value="Hard_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="2000">Hard</option>
  </select>
  <span class="price tc-price  hidden">
      <span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1,000</span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: And do a check, is the value of select is `Select Firmness_0` and in this case alert a `please select one` And one more, add another span into your span, because the awesome font icon will overwrited.

Comment: @karacsi_maci — That is other part of the story,my focus was more into how `jQuery.text()` works.. Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```js
$('.support-layer-firmness').on('change', function (e) {
   // onchange I am getting old value, if i select soft i am getting 0 instead of 1000
  alert($('.support-layer-firmness option:selected').attr('data-price'));
  $('span.amount').text($('.support-layer-firmness option:selected').attr('data-price'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="tmcp-field-wrap">
       <label for="tmcp_select_1"></label>
            <select class="tmcp-field support-layer-firmness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_0">
                         <option value="Select Firmness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="">Select Firmness</option>
                         <option value="soft" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1000">Soft</option>
                         <option value="medium" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1500">Medium</option>
                         <option value="hard" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="2000">Hard</option>    
             </select>
<span class="price tc-price  hidden">
     <span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1,000</span>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your jsfiddle ->[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz12qtqy/)

```
 $('.support-layer-firmness').on('change', function (e) {
   var value=$(this).find(':selected').attr('data-price');
   $('span.amount').text(value);
   alert(value);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
     $('.support-layer-firmness').on('change', function (e) {
         
         $('span.amount').hide(10);
         
         var price = $("option:selected").attr("data-price");
         
         $('span.amount').text(price);
          $('span.amount').show(1000,function(){
              alert(price);
          })
     })
  
 })
```

```html
<li class="tmcp-field-wrap">
            <label for="tmcp_select_1"></label>
            
            <select class="tmcp-field support-layer-firmness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_0">
                <option value="Select Firmness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="">Select Firmness</option>
                <option value="Soft_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1000">Soft</option>
                <option value="Medium_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1500">Medium</option>
                <option value="Hard_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="2000">Hard</option>    
            </select>
            
            <span class="price tc-price  hidden">
                <span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr">1000</i></span>
            </span>
            
</li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```